# How to display loading indicator during async call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

// post-thunk.js

```
import { postActions } from "./post-slice";

export const fetchPostData = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const postDataFunc = async () => {
      const resPro = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
      );
      if (!resPro.ok) {
        throw new Error("Error in fetching data!");
      }
      const resJson = await resPro.json();
      return resJson;
    };
    try {
      const postData = await postDataFunc();
      dispatch(postActions.replacePostList({ postList: postData || [] }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
  };
};
```

- making an api call and dispatching it.

// post-slice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: "postSlice",
  initialState: {
    postList: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    replacePostList(state, action) {
      state.postList = action.payload.postList;
    },
  },
});

export const postActions = postSlice.actions;
export default postSlice;
```

- created a redux slice, to define reducers.

// posts.js

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function Posts() {
  const storePosts = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.postReducer.postList;
  });
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {storePosts.map((element) => (
        <div key={element.id}>{element.title}</div>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

- posts.js is a component and displaying a list of 'post titles'.

I want to display a loader like `<div>loading ... </div>` in `<Posts>` component ie posts.js, while data is being fetched inside post-thunk.js, ie something like

```
{ isLoading &&  <div>Loading...</div>}
{ !isLoading && <display post title list>}
```

but I am unable to understand, how to recognize, when the data is loading and when data is completely fetched, inorder to set isLoading to 'true' or 'false'.
pls show me direction.

Comment: You should add a `loaded` property to your store and initialize it to `false`. Once the request receives a response, update it to `true`. You can watch the `loading` state similar to the way you watch `storePosts` in the component and show the loading ui accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the solution.

// post-thunk.js

```
import { postActions } from "./post-slice";

export const fetchPostData = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const postDataFunc = async () => {
      const resPro = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
      );
      if (!resPro.ok) {
        throw new Error("Error in fetching data!");
      }
      const resJson = await resPro.json();
      return resJson;
    };
    try {
      const postData = await postDataFunc();
      dispatch(postActions.replacePostList({ postList: postData || [] }));
      dispatch(postActions.loadingStatus({status: true}))
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
  };
};
```

// post-slice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: "postSlice",
  initialState: {
    postList: [],
    loading: false
  },
  reducers: {
    replacePostList(state, action) {
      state.postList = action.payload.postList;
    },
    loadingStatus(state,action){
      state.loading = action.payload.status;
    }
  },
});

export const postActions = postSlice.actions;
export default postSlice;
```

// posts.js

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function Posts() {
  const storePosts = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.postReducer.postList;
  });
  const loadingStatus = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.postReducer.loading;
  });

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loadingStatus &&
        storePosts.map((element) => (
          <div key={element.id}>{element.title}</div>
        ))}
      {!loadingStatus && <div>Loading ...</div>}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```